# Regex within Regex Groups in VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba, regex-group

I am coming from this question: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Found this very useful link there: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html

That is what I will use for the functions as I need to do this in VBA. However, the Regex that I am trying to solve is something like below:

```
OR(Q12 = "YES", Q13 = "ABCD", Q2 <> 3)
```

It will always only be `OR` function

I have 2 columns in my excel worksheet which are like:

```
Table1
    ColA   ColB
    Q1     YES
    Q2     2
    Q12    YES
    Q13    ABCD
```

So am trying to first make n groups:

```
Group1: Q12 = "YES"
Group2: Q13 = "ABCD"
Group3: Q2 <> 3
```

Then, I have to tackle every such group by again doing a Regex which will give me:

```
Group1-1: Q12
Group1-2: =
Group1-3: YES
```

And then I will `VLOOKUP(Q12, Table1, 2, FALSE)` within the VBA code.
If `Group1-2` is "=", then `=`, else `<>`  `Group1-3`

This will mean Group1 = 1
Similarly for all n Groups

TLDR:

**Input:**

```
OR(Q12 = "YES", Q13 = "ABCD", Q2 <> 3)
```

**Output:**

```
Group1-1: Q12
Group1-2: =
Group1-3: "YES"

Group2-1: Q13
Group2-2: =
Group2-3: "ABCD"

Group3-1: Q2
Group3-2: <>
Group3-3: 3
```

Thank you very much!

Edit1: Hey, instead of Hye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for using regular expressions at all :) Just remove commas and split by space:

```
Sub NoRegex()
    Dim str As String, splitted() As String
    str = "OR(Q12 = ""YES"", Q13 = ""ABCD"", Q2 <> 3)"
    str = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(str, ",", ""), "OR", ""), ")", ""), "(", "")

    splitted = Split(str, " ")
End Sub
```

You will have all your chunks in an array :)

Comment: Haha.. I guess it is this simple afterall.. Thank you so much! I just had one more qs on this - I do not know how many 'replaces' Ill have to put. Can range from 0 to 5 [0 as in some cases there wont be an OR function, it will just be a simple Q9 = "XYZ"

Comment: @spiff Just try it with  Q9 = "XYZ" yourself - it'll work :)